# Dynamically fetching the Json key value in Lua

Tags: arrays, json, lua

I have an input Json for which I need to get the value for a specific key. Key name will be dynamic and will be passed in input like below -

Input Json -

```json
{
    "error": "Bad Request"
    "source": [
        {
            "code": "400",
            "message": "Missing values"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I need to get the value for code and message dynamically. I am able to read the values if I give the path directly like below -

> json_body["source"][1].code

But here json path will be passed by user in input as string like below -

> local path = "source[1].code"

How can I use this path variable value and get the Json value for this key. I tried below but its not working -

> json_body[path]

Below is the sample Lua code which I am using -

```
local cjson = require("cjson.safe").new()

local function read_json_body(body)
    if body then
        return cjson.decode(body)
    end
end

local json_body = read_json_body(buffered_data)
local message_path = "source[1].code"
local value = json_body[message_path]
```

I am able to get the values for the fields which are outside of array like below -

```
local message_path = "error"
local value = json_body[message_path]
```

Comment: Try `local value = assert(load("return "..path, nil, "t", json_body))()`

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff for the response. I tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @EgorSkriptunoff below code worked -

`local value = assert(load("return "..path, nil, "t", json_body))()`